# Meaning of "on going."

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> *I focused my type-A personality **on going** to all the exercise
>   classes at the gym.* (Context: She is talking about how exercises has
>   changed her life. Before that she was a pretty asocial and miserable)

What does "on going" mean in this sentences? I think ıt is misused. I would use "by going" here.

Comment: "On" and "going" don't go together. "On" is the usual preposition used with "to focus": "Zoom in on one of his eyes, and **focus on** the pupil." "Today our **focus** will be **on** debt consolidation." So in this example, she is **focusing on** the activity of **going to the gym**.

Comment: Yes. I overlooked the other part of the sentence, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking at the wrong part of the sentence here.

I believe you want to consider:

> To focus [something] on [something else].

**To focus on**: to give most of your attention to someone or something [Def.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-british-english/focus-on-someone-something)